# Can we use multiple SSL certificates for single instance with multiple user logins

Tags: tls

I am using a product for archiving mails and providing the same instance for couple of other companies as well with each company admin having his own credentials to manage their company policies.
But the problem here is some people are asking to provide the secure HTTPS connection and some doesn't want it.
Can I add a SSL certificate to that product and make it applicable only for customers who want to use a secure connection.

If it requires a changes at product level also please suggest them, so that I can suggest the same to the company that sell the product.

Comment: There is nothing known about the product except that it seems to be possible to use HTTPS  with it. There is no general way to configure an arbitrary product for both HTTP and HTTPS depending on some shallow specified user requirements. To find out if the specific requirements are possible to implement with the specific product you need to contact the vendor of the product.

Comment: Unclear what do you mean `add a SSL certificate to that product` . Is it some sort of web services or server program ? If web services, is everyone access the same host name ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question that only the vendor can answer.

Comment: Yes you can close it Mr.Tom as i found some information from NGINX side as mentioned by Praneeth.  Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your question is unclear.

Do you want to configure multiple SSL certificates for the same domain? That's meaningless. But you could buy multiples certificates for the same domain from providers like GoDaddy or NameCheap.

Suppose, if your domain is `mail-archive.example.com`. You could be able to grant access via both, HTTP and HTTPS. Clients would be able to access the site in both ways, `https://mail-archive.example.com` & `http://mail-archive.example.com` with their respective credentials.

On Nginx, your config should be something like:

```
    server {

            listen 80;
            listen [::]:80;

            server_name mail-archive.example.com;
            root /var/www/html/mail-archive/public;
            index index.php index.html index.htm;

}

    server {

        listen 443 http2;
        listen [::]:443 http2;

        server_name mail-archive.example.com;

        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/mail-archive.example.pem; (or bundle.crt)
        ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/mail-archive.example.key;

        root /var/www/html/mail-archive/public;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

    }
```

Pass the HTTPS domain for clients those who want to access the site over a secure connection and HTTP domain for those who don't want.

Keep in mind, newer versions of Google Chrome throw a warning if data is submitted over a non-secure connection.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, just forcing all of your customers to use HTTPS may be the best solution. Email backups are sensitive, so sending them over unencrypted connection is not necessarily desirable, even if they are encrypted and especially if they are not. While providing the option for admins to choose is nice of you, it could lower security even for the admins that chose to use HTTPS if not done carefully.

Secondly, while you could just allow both HTTP and HTTPS as described by Praneeth Karnena, it would prevent you from using important security features such as HSTS. I would personally use sub-domains if I had to. So I would have `secure.example.com` and `insecure.example.com`. Therefore the admins that don't want to use HTTPS can't decrease the security of those that do. You would have to slightly modify how the app, so it would recognioze which sub-domain was used and include or not include the HSTS headers depending on that. You could also refuse to log-in admins who opted for the secure version on the insecure version of the site.

Comment: I like this answer. Two separate sub-domains, one with HTTPs (and HSTS and redirects) and one without HTTPs